# Bash script to check the string in the last column of a file and manipulate it into an integer

Tags: bash, shell

I have a sample comma delimited text file that looks like;

```
9ZJ,Name 1,Not Covered,Home Furniture & Decor,Consumer Cyclical,104.0g
H3L,H3llo name,Stopped Coverage,Software - Code,Services,177.0g
ABA,Another name here,Not Covered,Farm - Rural - Country,Farm Services,223.6g
ABC,ABC Name there,4-star Coverage,Home,Bricks & motar,1.9Meg
ABD,Abacus Name Number 1,3-star Coverage,Maths - Science,Further study,2.6Meg
```

I want to check the string in the last column, if the string ends with a 'g' then I want to manipulate the string and convert it into an integer, essentially stripping the 'g' from the string in the last column and multiple it with 10, eg. 223.6g becomes 2236. If the string ends with a 'Meg' then I want to manipulate the string and convert it into an integer, essentially stripping the 'Meg' from the string in the last column and multiple it with 1000, eg. 1.9Meg becomes 1900. How do I do this string manipulation in a bash script?

Comment: Show us what you've got so far for your bash script. What do you need help with in particular? Break it down into pieces. Do you know how to (1) Loop over each line of a file? (2) Pull out the last column of a CSV file? (3) Check if a string has a particular suffix? (4) Strip off a suffix? (5) Multiply floating point numbers? We can help you with any of these if you tell us where you're stuck.

Comment: @JohnKugelman great explanation :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using awk. Tweak as needed...

```
za:tmp za$ cat /tmp/file.txt 
9ZJ,Name 1,Not Covered,Home Furniture & Decor,Consumer Cyclical,104.0g
H3L,H3llo name,Stopped Coverage,Software - Code,Services,177.0g
ABA,Another name here,Not Covered,Farm - Rural - Country,Farm Services,223.6g
ABC,ABC Name there,4-star Coverage,Home,Bricks & motar,1.9Meg
ABD,Abacus Name Number 1,3-star Coverage,Maths - Science,Further study,2.6Meg

za:tmp za$ awk -F, '$(NF) ~ /g/ {print $(NF) * 10 }' </tmp/file.txt 
1040
1770
2236
19
26
```

Comment: Thanks zee for the starter tip, really appreciate it (sometimes we just need a little bit of positive direction/tip to get going, unlike John Kugelman user who has to be nasty above). So the code is as follow;

awk -F, '{ if ($(NF) ~ /g/) {print $(NF) * 10 } else if ($(NF) ~ /Meg/) {print $(NF) * 1000 } }' <file.csv

Comment: @user3289583 I think you misunderstood John's kind and constructive offer of assistance targeted at any aspect of the problem you are having difficulty with. You don't get to 250k+ of reputation without being a dedicated, helpful, consistent contributor.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Agree.